# Make flex slider display images with corresponding links

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have flexslider installed on my wordpress and working great, the way it works, it grabs all the images attached to the page and displays them, is it possible to make every image links to its file?

the code I am using is this

```
<ul class="slides">

    <php foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {  ?>

        <li><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'cw-post' ); ?>
        </li>

    <?php } ?>

</ul>
```

Comment: Im not sure how this helps with my question?

Comment: What plugin are you using?  I don't see anything on the .org website just named "flexslider", so I can't really look into it.  But I just don't understand why you don't just use a plugin that already has that functionality

Comment: The plugin is called flexslider, http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/ I have integrated it in my theme, the only reason why I am asking this question is because I got everything working and love the way it looks after all the customization, all I need is to make it every image that it displays link to that corresponding image!

Comment: it wont be ideal for me to start over with a new plugin when I got this whole thing working exactly and looks exactly that way I want it, all I need is making the slides link!

Comment: If I can figure out how to make it link, I can integrate it with Jetpack Carousel, unless you have a way to show me how to make jetpack carousel display as a featured gallery ;) just like in flexslider

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the trick.

```
// Get ID of the attached file
$thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID());

// Get attached file. Define what size at the end. DEfault is the thumbnail.
$image_src_arr = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumbnail_id,'medium');

// Return image source
$image_source = $image_src_arr[0];
```

I've created this function for myeslf:

```
/**
 * This function will return source url for attached image-
 * The get_the_ID is a global WP command that will retrieve current post / page ID
 * Using the post ID it will return the attachment ID needed in order to call
 * wp_get_Attachment_image_src.
 */
function get_related_image($size){
    $image_src_arr = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()),$size);

    if(sizeof($image_src_arr) > 0) {
        return $image_src_arr[0];
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more on this? where do I put the above code? I just tried it in my functions.php and no go :(

Comment: the code that I posed is my post_format.php (ex standard.php, image.php)

Comment: Added some more info to the function. In order to use this, you must have enabled `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); ` inside functions.php. Then you must attach a image to the post / page.